# pyflink JDBC Postgresql Catalog throwing errors for data type UUID , How to handle the uuid datatype in Flink Table API?

Tags: postgresql, apache-flink, pyflink, flink-table-api

Apache Flink 1.11.0
Python Table API
Catalog : postgresql

Reading and writing data from postgresql Catalog tables which coantain UUID data type columns through Table API throwing UUID data type unsupportedOperatorException.

How to handle the UUID dataype in pyFlink?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about PostgreSQL's type system. Is UUID datatype a type similar to string? The type supported by PyFlink is basically the same as the type of Flink's Table. For details, you can refer to the document[1]

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/python/table-api-users-guide/python_types.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like There isn't an elegant way to handle Postgres UUIDs off the bat yet, but this is something that will be covered once the Table API's type system rework is completed. I found the JIRA for the same : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19869